# MySQL select complete last month

Tags: mysql, sql, date, where-clause

How to select all data from last month (or 30 days)?

I already found some answers, and mostly gives this solution

```
SELECT * 
FROM gigs
WHERE date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
ORDER BY date DESC
```

But this gives me also the dates from the future

I am only interested in the days from last month or 30 days (not next month and beyond)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
WHERE date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND date <= CURRENT_DATE
```

I added a condition so the query filters on date not greater than today. I also modified your code so the date range starts one month ago (you had 3 months).

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
SELECT * FROM gigs
WHERE date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND CURDATE()
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for two separate things.

The last 30 days is easy.

```
date between now() - interval 30 day and now()
```

Data this month is like this:

```
date between (last_day(Now() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY) and last_day(Now())
```

Data a few months ago is like this:

```
date between (last_day(Now() - INTERVAL 4 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
       and  
             (last_day(Now() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: both solutions will also give future dates

Comment: You just needed the "and date < now()"